# VSCode - How to debug a React project thats imported as a module into another React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have two React projects, one is packaged and used as a node_module in the other.  I am able to create a debug configuration for the main project (the project which uses the other as a module), but with this configuration I am not able to set breakpoints in the other project.

I am looking to figure out how to configure the debugger in VSCode in order to be able to run both locally and set breakpoints in each project.

Unfortunately the second project does not have a single port it consistently runs on.  I am thinking I need to use the `Attach to process` configuration type, am I on the right track there?